# zsh on MacOS: how to create an associative array (hash table) from the from two column-like scalars?

Tags: macos, zsh, associative-array

I have two scalar values in the form of columns:

```
% echo $key
hom
doc
fam

echo $val
'home'
'Documents'
'Family'
```

and I want to create associative array from them.

I'm aware about the method of creation the associative array like below:

```
declare -A my_assoc_arr
my_assoc_arr=(hom home doc Documents fam Family)
```

But what is the easiest method create an associative array by digesting `$key` and `$val` in the form as I have them (scalar, column-like)? Is there any other association syntax, or I need to put my effort into reshuffling  `$key` and `$val` to the association syntax above?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to parse the `alias` statements themselves? And what's the point of `cd ~`, rather than plain `cd` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell what do you mean by /parse the `alias` statements themselves/? And treat `cd ~` as dummy example :-) My list of aliases are quite long.

Comment: **zsh** has a built-in variable `aliases` defined as an associative table of all aliases. Why bother making the table by yourself...?

Comment: @SimonSmith the idea is to check what aliases I’ve got defined via `.zshrc` and enumerate them via foreach loop over the associative table

Comment: Are you trying to find aliases created by yourself (i.e., not by plugins)?

Comment: Still don't understand why you do this manually. If you want to write a loop by scanning `~/.zshrc`, you can try`awk '/^\s*alias\s/ {sub(/^\s*alias/,""); sub(/=/,"\n"); print $0}' ~/.zshrc | while IFS=' ' read -r k; do IFS= read -r v; printf '%s:%s\n' "$k" "$v"; done`. Replace the `printf` command with whatever you have in mind. And there's no need to create an associative table... If you want one, then create it inside the loop by appending key-value pairs to an empty-initialized associative array.

Comment: @SimonSmith first of all thank you. Secondly yes, I'm trying to find aliases created by myself. To clarify the situation I rephrase my question detaching it from aliases context.

Comment: Are `key` and `val` already arrays, or just newline-delimited strings?

Comment: newline-delimited strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a loop, but it's not too messy. You'll just use two `read` commands to read a line from each string at one time.

```
typeset -A arr

while IFS= read -u 3 -r k
      IFS= read -u 4 -r v
do
    arr[$k]=$v
done 3<<< $key 4<<< $val
```

The first `read` reads from file descriptor 3 (which is redirected from a here string created from `$key`, the second from file descriptor 4 (likewise redirected from `$val`).

```
$ typeset -p arr
typeset -A arr=( [doc]=Documents [fam]=Family [hom]=home )
```

(This assumes `key` and `val` have the same number of lines. I don't want to go down the rabbit hole of dealing with the alternative, which makes you decide what to do with leftover keys or values.)

Answer (score 3):

In `zsh` you can also use the 'zip' operator to reshuffle two standard arrays into the associative array syntax you mentioned:

```bash
typeset -a keys=("${(f@)key}") vals=("${(f@)val}")
typeset -A arr=("${(@)keys:^vals}")
```

Some of the pieces:

- `${(f)...}` - uses the `f` parameter expansion flag to split a string on newlines.
- `"${(@)...}"` - ensures that empty values and values with spaces are handled (probably not absolutely necessary here).
- `${...:^...}` - zips two arrays together, alternating values from each array. The resulting array will be twice the length of the shortest input array.
- `typeset -A arr=(k1 v1 k2 v2)` - creates an associative array from the alternating keys and values.

Comment: Interesting, I don't think I ever noticed the zip operator before.